# Adding a dictionary to a row in a Pandas DataFrame using concat in pandas 1.4

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

After updating to pandas 1.4, I now receive the following warning when using frame.append to append a dictionary to a Pandas DataFrame.

```
FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be
removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
```

Below is the code. This still works, though I would like to resolve the warning.

```
report = report.append({
                "period":period,
                "symbol":symbol,
                "start_date":start_date,
                "start_price":start_price,
                "start_market_cap":start_market_cap,
                "end_date":end_date,
                "end_price":end_price,
                "end_market_cap":end_market_cap,
                "return":return_
            },ignore_index=True)
```

I have updated the code to the below, which kicks a different warning:

```
report = pd.concat([report,{
                "period":period,
                "symbol":symbol,
                "start_date":start_date,
                "start_price":start_price,
                "start_market_cap":start_market_cap,
                "end_date":end_date,
                "end_price":end_price,
                "end_market_cap":end_market_cap,
                "return":return_
            }],ignore_index=True)

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'dict'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

2 questions:
Is the first warning wrong?
What is the pandas 1.4 way to achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: deprecated in pandas 1.4.0 https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `loc` to assign a single row value:

```
report.loc[len(report)] = {"period":period,
                           "symbol":symbol,
                           "start_date":start_date,
                           "start_price":start_price,
                           "start_market_cap":start_market_cap,
                           "end_date":end_date,
                           "end_price":end_price,
                           "end_market_cap":end_market_cap,
                           "return":return_
                          }
```

Answer (score 10):

The answer posted by @fantabolous will work even if the `df` is empty with no columns.

```py
import pandas as pd 
df =  pd.DataFrame(columns=[])
data_dict = {"a":0,"b":2742,"c":13.38867188,"d":0}
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([data_dict])], ignore_index=True)
df
```

Answer (score 2):

```
report = pd.concat([report, pd.DataFrame([mydict])], ignore_index=True)
```

where `mydict` is the row you want added.

Unlike `append`, `concat` does not support dicts directly.

[`append` was deprecated in pandas 1.4.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append)